# Remove very first character in file

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to remove the very first character (") from a file which contains a JSON String. I'm using Python for this. Below is my code:

```
jsonOutput = 'JsonString_{}.{}'.format(str(uuid.uuid1()), "json")
jsonOutput_File = os.path.join(arcpy.env.scratchFolder, jsonOutput)

with open(jsonOutput_File, 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(jsonString, json_file)

// I was able to remove the very last character using the code below
with open(jsonOutput_File, 'r+') as read_json_file:
    read_json_file.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)
    read_json_file.truncate()
```

Basically when I dump the JSON String to a file, the String is getting surrounded by double quotes. I'm trying to remove these double quotes from the first & last position of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have a JSON string, simply write it to the file.

Encoding the JSON string to JSON again using `json.dump()` is a bad idea and will not be fixed as simple as removing a leading and a trailing quote.

Consider the following minimal and complete example:

```
import json
import os
import uuid

myobject = {"hello": "world"}
jsonString = json.dumps(myobject)
jsonOutput = 'JsonString_{}.{}'.format(str(uuid.uuid1()), "json")
jsonOutput_File = os.path.join("d:\\", jsonOutput)
with open(jsonOutput_File, 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(jsonString, json_file)
```

The output is a file with the content:

```
"{\"hello\": \"world\"}"
```

Removing the quotes will **not** make it valid JSON.

Instead, avoid the duplicate JSON creation, either by removing `json.dumps()` which converts the object to JSON one time, or by removing `json.dump()`, which does it a second time.

Solution 1:

```
import json
import os
import uuid

myobject = {"hello": "world"}
                                          # <-- deleted line here
jsonOutput = 'JsonString_{}.{}'.format(str(uuid.uuid1()), "json")
jsonOutput_File = os.path.join("d:\\", jsonOutput)
with open(jsonOutput_File, 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(myobject, json_file)        # <-- changed to object here
```

Solution 2:

```
import json
import os
import uuid

myobject = {"hello": "world"}
jsonString = json.dumps(myobject)
jsonOutput = 'JsonString_{}.{}'.format(str(uuid.uuid1()), "json")
jsonOutput_File = os.path.join("d:\\", jsonOutput)
with open(jsonOutput_File, 'w') as json_file:
    json_file.write(jsonString)                # <-- Note this line
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks @Thomas. I just wrote my JSON String to the file using .write. Thanks for the explanation as well. :)

Comment: @LegendKiller: if this solution works for you, please tick the checkmark at the top left of this answer so that others know the problem is solved. Thanks.